# Laravel PUT method not working in ajax post with form serialize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In Post edit form, changed form method to PUT using @method('PUT')

```
<form action="{{ route('user.update', ['id' => $user->id]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="create-user-form">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="personal-details">
    <div class="form-floating mb-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $user->name }}">
       <label for="title">{{ __('Title') }} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    </div>
       //Some other fields
</div>
<div class="text-center mt-2 mb-2">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="userupdate">Update User</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I try to validate this form through ajax call. But it throws an error 405 Method Not Allowed (The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.)
**Here is my ajax code**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#userupdate', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}" }
        });
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('users.validate') }}",
            data: $('#create-user-form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success)
                {
                    $('#create-user-form').submit();
                }
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Then changed the form data to

```
data: {$('#create-user-form').serialize(), '_method':'PUT'},
```

In this case it shows **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string**

Here is my route

```
Route::put('user/update/{id}', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');
Route::post('user/validate', 'UserController@validateRequest')->name('users.validate');
```

Comment: Your route is defined as a POST route, not a PUT route

Comment: Yes, Is there any solution without changing routes

Comment: You can change the form method to POST or change the route. (remove the `@method('PUT')`)

Comment: Specify the type for your Ajax request to be PUT.

Comment: Its not working same error

Comment: @Sambhu and why is it that you don't want to change/add the route?

Comment: Because, the same route used for some another pages validation

Comment: @Sambhu then add a put route..

Answer (score 0):

Change input button type like **type="button"**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="userupdate">Update User</button>
```

You need to add the form method "POST" into the form **serialize**

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // convert form to array
data.push({name: "_method", value: 'POST'});
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).on('click', '#userupdate', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}" }
    });
    var element = $(this);
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // convert form to array
    data.push({name: "_method", value: 'POST'});
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('users.validate') }}",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success)
            {
                $('#create-user-form').submit();
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```